# Jupyter Notebook Failing VSCode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-extensions

When I attempt to run a Jupiter notebook in VS Code with a simple `print("hello world")` command,I get the following error printout:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

With this info in the Jupyter log

```
error 15:07:35.321: Error in execution (get message for cell) Er [Error]: Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

    at Sm.rejectStartPromise (/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:254981)
    at t._complete (/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:255541)
    at t.n (/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700797)
    at t.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:701037)
    at t.complete (/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:700930)
    at t._complete (/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699446)
    at t.complete (/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:699145)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/joshpurtell/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:2:1800927)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  category: 'jupyterconnection'
}
```

However, when I run the command `jupyter-notebook` in the python terminal with the same environment activated, I have no issue and it runs as expected.

Comment: This error just occured out of the blue for me as well. Any progress on this @Josh Purtell?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Python Interpreter you've set in VSCode has Jupyter installed? Sometimes it changes on me when I restart personally

Comment: Yes. I am using a venv, and jupyter 1.0.0 is installed

Comment: The output of the notebook cell is as follows:
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Failed to start Jupyter Server as the packages 'jupyter' and 'notebook' could not be located in the Python environment '/bin/python'. 
View Jupyter log for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Activate your `venv`.

Make sure `ipykernel` package is installed and run

`ipython kernel install --name "<you_venv_name_here>" --user`

Restart VsCode.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Still getting the same errors after following these steps. I restarted the machine as well and still no change..

Comment: Make sure you set your venv in the top right of the notebook